# What comparator does Vuetify use to sort data table String columns

Tags: sorting, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuetify.js, v-data-table

If I take the standard Vuetify example and change Calories to contain Strings, and now the data are not all numeric:
https://codepen.io/hobbeschild/pen/WNQWmrJ

then what comparator is Vuetify using internally to order these Strings?

Say I have another page with a v-select on it, and I want to give the user all the Calorie options that were on the other page in the table, and I want to show in the same order that they were in the table when Calories were sorted in ascending order.  How could I replicate that?

I think I need to do something like this before populating the v-select (this doesn't sort them quite right but I think it will be something similar):

```
calories.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }))
```

I am imagining that internally the v-data-table code does a localeCompare or something similar and I just need the arguments it uses.

Comment: You might wanna have a look at the prop called `custom-sort`.

Comment: @YomS. I don't want to put a custom sort on the table.  The table is fine.  It can stay as it is.  I want to know what it's doing behind the scenes on the default sort.  What comparator is it using?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be this

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/268434aa851dded8b67c0e67bfa39b3cbe791584/packages/vuetify/src/util/helpers.ts#L285

Though I am not sure how to reference the sortItems method directly.  When I add

```
import { sortItems } from "vuetify/src/util/helpers";
```

I get an error "Can't resolve 'vuetify/src/util/helpers'".

Answer (score 0):

@hobbes_child  comment
I change to import from lib is resolved

```
import { sortItems } from "vuetify/lib/util/helpers";
```